# Estimating latency via distance and betweenness

Tags: routing, internet, latency, speed, network-access

I want to compute the relationship between delay (latency) with distance and betweenness. More specifically, if I know (let's assume) that the distance and betweenness values for two different autonomous systems (one sender & one receiver) is 2 and 3 respectively, is there a formula or something like that to estimate the latency between these two ASes? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, so we can't recommend "_relative papers_".

Comment: Ok, sorry didnt know it. But maybe someone can still give me personal advices for my issue.?

Comment: Distance does have a direct relationship to latency on a single, direct link, but having network devices between your two devices can add variable latency based on how congested the links are, and how busy the routers and/or switches in between are, and this can manifest itself during particular times of day, or at random times. Traffic will be queued (delayed, increasing latency, for seemingly random amounts of time).

Comment: Also, the latency of the single, direct link will have a relationship to the medium of the link (e.g. copper and fiber have different latencies, and wireless has a different latency from either of those).

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

Firstly "Latency between AS's" doesn't really make much sense as a concept. Many AS's span the globe. The latency between two geographically close points in dfferent AS's can easilly be far less than the latency between two geographically distant points in the same AS.

The default way of keeping traffic between two globe-spanning ASs local was/is to use ["hot potato"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot-potato_and_cold-potato_routing) routing. Basically you get the traffic out of your AS as quickly as possible and let the destination AS worry about where in the world the user is.

Some ASs may instead chose to request and respect "multi-exit discriminators" in the routing information they receive so that local traffic stays local while long distance traffic remains in the source AS for longer.

Given that AS's can range from something that sits in a single room to something that spans the globe the number of AS's involved isn't really going to be a good indication of latency either.